# Anypic upload multi photos at once

Tags: parse-platform

At this moment, Anypic Can just upload one photo every time. If you have more photos of one holiday, it is really not handy to upload them one by one, and then you need scroll down to see all of them. Can it upload multi photos at once , and then can it show them in small sizes?

Comment: Does anyone know this? Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it in Objective  C?